# How to use models from associations in views with HABTM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a @friend model that has_and_belongs_to_many @interests and vice versa. Each interest has a name:string. How do I show all the interests by their name next to each friend?

I tried

```
friend.interests.count
```

which shows the correct number, but for

```
friend.interests.first
```

the result is

`#<Interest:0x00007f959e103250>`

How do I display the name of this interest from the database in a view?

```
<%= friend.interests.count %>
<%= friend.interests.first %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the name of the interest, just by accessing the `friend.interests.first.name`. And for listing all the interests you can iterate and show the name of them.

```
    <% friend.interests.each do |interest| %>
      <%= interest.name %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Aarthi. However, if I do friend.interests.first.name I get the error "undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: Does the friend has any interests?. I.e is the `friend.interests.count > 0` ?

Comment: Yes, added through the console.

Comment: Can you share the friend record and it's interests records, please?.

Comment: .5.1 :001 > friend = Friend.first
  Friend Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "friends".* FROM "friends" ORDER BY "friends"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Friend id: 1, first_name: "fwefefw", last_name: "fwefwef", age: 29, birthdate: "2014-08-20", created_at: "2019-08-20 18:36:23", updated_at: "2019-08-20 18:36:23", user_id: 1>

Comment: 2.5.1 :002 > friend.interests
  Interest Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "interests".* FROM "interests" INNER JOIN "friends_interests" ON "interests"."id" = "friends_interests"."interest_id" WHERE "friends_interests"."friend_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["friend_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Interest id: 1, name: "Interest01", created_at: "2019-08-20 18:44:29", updated_at: "2019-08-20 19:01:34">, #<Interest id: 5, name: "edffdsfsf", created_at: "2019-08-21 19:17:36", updated_at: "2019-08-21 19:17:36">]> 
2.5.1 :003 >

Comment: `friend = Friend.first 
friend.interests.each do |i| 
p i.name 
end` 

TRy this in rails console. each in a separate line.

Comment: Thanks, Aarthi. That worked! I had to loop through the friend to get each interest.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the attribute after the object:

```
<%= friend.interests.first.name %>
```